# Is python Counter expected to behave as follows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have a list of dictionaries as follows

```
[
    {'sex': 2, 'newspaper_sheet__country': 'ML', 'n': 7},
    {'sex': 1, 'newspaper_sheet__country': 'ML', 'n': 5},
    {'sex': 2, 'newspaper_sheet__country': 'ML', 'n': 10}
]
```

I then have 2 Counters

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
counts1 = Counter()
```

I'm updating the two counters in the following formats

```
for row in rows:
    counts.update({(row['sex'], row['newspaper_sheet__country']): row['n']})
```

and

```
counts1.update({(row['sex'], row['newspaper_sheet__country']): row['n'] for row in rows})
```

I would expect the values of the 2 counts to be the same since the only difference is 1 is using a for loop and the other one a dict comprehension.

Why are the 2 values different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `Counter.update` in each iteration of a `for` loop the `Counter` object would get updated with the input dict for each call.

With a dict comprehension, key-values get aggregated into a dict first before getting passed to `Counter.update`. Since latter values of duplicating keys in a dict comprehension would override the preceding values of the same keys, the value `10` of the key `(2, 'ML')` overrides the value `7` of the same key, resulting in the `Counter` object not accounting for the value `7` in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Because calling `.update` in a loop like that is not equivalent to passing the result of that dictionary comprehension, look what that dictionary comprehension creates:

```
>>> rows = [
...     {'sex': 2, 'newspaper_sheet__country': 'ML', 'n': 7},
...     {'sex': 1, 'newspaper_sheet__country': 'ML', 'n': 5},
...     {'sex': 2, 'newspaper_sheet__country': 'ML', 'n': 10}
... ]
>>> {(row['sex'], row['newspaper_sheet__country']): row['n'] for row in rows}
{(2, 'ML'): 10, (1, 'ML'): 5}
```

Dictionaries have unique keys, and the last item seen is kept.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is because of the way `update()` is done with list comprehension.

With for loop based approach, the counter is updated each time and aggregates the count for the matching keys but with the list comprehension approach, it is only getting a dictionary with unique keys.

The list comprehension approach can be broken down as:

```
dic = {(row['sex'], row['newspaper_sheet__country']): row['n'] for row in rows}
print(dic)  # dic only contains unique key value pairs here
counts1.update(dic)
```

So, `counts1` is updated just once while `counts` is updated multiple times due to the loop based approach.